# Moving ImageView with G Sensor

Tags: java, android

i want to do something like parallax, so I use the G Sensor 
and want to move the image with it.

My problem is there's only old tutorials I guess and 
google something changed?

```
public class ShowWallpaper extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorListener {

ImageView imageViewWallpaper;
ImageButton ib_back;
Button setWallpaper;
TextView tv_text;

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;

private Sensor mySensor;
private SensorManager SM;

public static float x = 0;
public static float y = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_wallpaper);

    imageViewWallpaper = findViewById(R.id.showCustom);
    ib_back = findViewById(R.id.ib_back);
    setWallpaper = findViewById(R.id.btnSetWallpaper);

    tv_text = findViewById(R.id.tv_test);


    SM = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mySensor = SM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    SM.registerListener(this,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(extras.getString("SRC")).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

            imageViewWallpaper.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    WallpaperManager wpm = (WallpaperManager) getSystemService(WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
                    try {
                        wpm.setBitmap(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(ShowWallpaper.this, "Hintergrund wurde gesetzt.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });



    ib_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(int i, float[] floats) {

    x -=  floats[0];
    y +=  floats[1];

    imageViewWallpaper.setX(x);
    imageViewWallpaper.setY(y);

/*
    //imageViewWallpaper.setX(Math.round(floats[0]) /2);
    //imageViewWallpaper.setY(Math.round(floats[1]) /2);

    imageViewWallpaper.setX(imageViewWallpaper.getHeight()/2);
    imageViewWallpaper.setY(imageViewWallpaper.getWidth()/2);

    if(Math.round(floats[0]) < 0){
        lp.setMargins(0,0,Math.round(floats[0]*10),Math.round(floats[1]*10));
    }else {
        lp.setMargins(Math.round(floats[0]*10),Math.round(floats[1]*10),0,0);
    }



    imageViewWallpaper.setLayoutParams(lp);*/


    tv_text.setText("X - " + String.valueOf(floats[0]) + " Y - " + floats[1]);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

When using this code the image moves away. I tried the most of answer from this site but nothings working.

[image: Screenshot]
On the top you can see the g sensor x y by holding the smartphone normaly.

Is it possible that my G Sensor not working correctly?

Thanks